# How to display the given string in vertical form in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

like I have the string 'My name is Kirti' and my output should be

```
My 
name 
is 
Kirti
```

Output should be in such a way new word in next line

Comment: Your question has zero to do with PL/SQL. I removed the tag to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

For example (the first 2 lines represent sample data - your input string; query begins in line #3):

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'My name is Kirti' from dual)
  3  select regexp_substr(col, '[^ ]+', 1, level) val
  4  from test
  5  connect by level <= regexp_count(col, ' ') + 1;

VAL
-------------------------------------------------------------
My
name
is
Kirti

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

If "words" are separated by a single space, then it's as easy as

```
select translate('My name is Kirti', chr(32), chr(10)) as result from dual;

RESULT          
----------------
My
name
is
Kirti
```

The function `translate` translates (replaces), in the input string given as the first argument, every individual character from the second argument with the corresponding character from the third argument. In this case, we replace a single character, space (`chr(32)`) with a newline (`chr(10)`). It this case, I prefer to write the characters using the `chr()` function so that it is 100% clear to anyone reading the query what it is supposed to do.

Of course, if sometimes the words are separated by two spaces, or they may be separated by tab, etc., the query is more complicated - but not too much so.